# how to make soup less 'meaty'?

Tags: soup

Salut!

Using a hambone left over from the holidays, I made some split pea soup. The problem is that, deviating from the recipe, I added ham as well as the hambone.

Now, the soup is so meaty  it is quite overwhelming- at room temperature the liquid turns into jelly.

I tried adding a few glugs of lemon juice but that doesn't seem to have helped. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you rendered too much gelatin into the soup, a couple easy fixes are to either:

- prepare another batch of the soup omitting the ham and bone and then marry the two over a medium/high heat
- thin with a low fat/nonfat liquid like milk or water (unfortunately a side effect will be of increased separation in the soup as it cools) the lower the fat content of what you add the more it will separate. ie adding 2% milk will cause less separating than skim milk

Comment: I agree that the only solution is dilution- however, it isn't fat. If it were fat the solution would be simple- skim the fat off the top. The gel is the gelatin from the meat and bones and the overwhelming flavor is just because the meat was packed with so much salt and flavorings.